# How can I properly check all the neighboring elements? (AOC 2023 day 3 part 1)

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java while solving AOC 2023.
I am stuck on Day 3 Part 1.

I tried debugging and even trying to see the output line by line, and in the first 15 lines my code works fine, and it doesn't make any sense to look at 140 lines of input filled with dots.

I don't understand which edge cases my code doesn't cover:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class ThreeAOC {
    public static List<String> file;
    public static int LINES;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            file = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input3"));
            LINES = file.size();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++) {
            String [] numbers = LineSpliter(file.get(i));                
            total += NumberChecker(numbers, i, file.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);

    }

    public static String[] LineSpliter(String line) {
        return Arrays.stream(line.split("\\D+"))
                .filter(s -> !s.isBlank())
                .toArray(String[]::new);       
    }

    public static int NumberChecker(String[] numbers, int lineIndex, String line) {
        int lineLength = file.get(lineIndex).length() - 1;
        int subTotal = 0;
        for (String number : numbers) {
            //System.out.println("Checking number: " + number);
            for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {

                int currentCharIndex = file.get(lineIndex).indexOf(number) + i;
                int nextCharIndex = currentCharIndex == lineLength ? -1 : currentCharIndex + 1;
                int previousCharIndex = currentCharIndex == 0 ? -1 : currentCharIndex - 1;


                int nextLine = lineIndex == (LINES - 1) ? -1 : lineIndex + 1;
                int previousLine = lineIndex == 0 ? -1 : lineIndex - 1;

                boolean leftSide = LeftOrRight(previousCharIndex, -1, -1, lineIndex);
                boolean rightSide = LeftOrRight(-1, nextCharIndex, -1, lineIndex);

                boolean previousLeftSide = LeftOrRight(previousCharIndex, -1, -1, previousLine);
                boolean previousRightSide = LeftOrRight(-1, nextCharIndex, -1, previousLine);

                boolean nextLeftSide = LeftOrRight(previousCharIndex, -1, -1, nextLine);
                boolean nextRightSide = LeftOrRight(-1, nextCharIndex, -1, nextLine);

                boolean currentPositionPreviousLine = previousLine < 0 ? false : LeftOrRight(-1, -1, currentCharIndex, previousLine);
                boolean currentPositionNextLine = nextLine < 0 ? false : LeftOrRight(-1, -1, currentCharIndex, nextLine);
                //System.out.println("DOING CURRENT POSITION");

                if (leftSide || rightSide || previousLeftSide || previousRightSide || currentPositionPreviousLine || nextLeftSide || nextRightSide || currentPositionNextLine) {
                    subTotal += Integer.parseInt(number);
                    //String newLine = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(number)) + ".".repeat(number.length()) + line.substring(line.indexOf(number) + number.length());
                    //String newLine = line.replace(number, );
                    //file.set(lineIndex, newLine);
                    System.out.println(number);
                    break;
                }                                
            }
        }
        return subTotal;
    }

    public static boolean LeftOrRight(int previousCharIndex, int nextCharIndex, int currentCharIndex, int lineIndex) {
        if (lineIndex < 0) {
            return false;            
        }

        char previousChar = previousCharIndex < 0 ? '.' : file.get(lineIndex).charAt(previousCharIndex);
        //System.out.println("Previous char: " + previousChar + "Previous Char Index: " + previousCharIndex);

        char nextChar = nextCharIndex < 0 ? '.' : file.get(lineIndex).charAt(nextCharIndex);
        //System.out.println("Next char: " + nextChar + "Next Char Index: " + nextCharIndex);


        char currentChar = currentCharIndex < 0 ? '.' : file.get(lineIndex).charAt(currentCharIndex);
        //System.out.println("Current char: " + currentChar + "Current Char Index: " + currentCharIndex);



        boolean leftSide = previousCharIndex < 0 ? false: previousChar != '.' && !Character.isDigit(previousChar);  

        boolean rightSide = nextCharIndex < 0 ? false : nextChar != '.' && !Character.isDigit(nextChar);

        boolean currentPosition = currentCharIndex < 0 ? false : currentChar != '.' && !Character.isDigit(currentChar);

        if (leftSide || rightSide || currentPosition) {
            return true;            
        }
        return false;    
    }
}
```